# Extract all functions called in a python script

Tags: python

I have a package and a script that calls the functions in the package. The package itself is relatively large and serves multiple purposes, and I am trying to extract the functions used in the package that is just enough for running a specific script.

So my question is: for a given script, is it possible to extract all functions in the package that are actually used in this script? For example, suppose I have a package with the following structure:

```
mypackage
- __init__.py
- mymodule.py
  - func1
  - func2
```

Then I have another script that calls `func1` from `mypackage` as well as some other functions such as `numpy` in the python environment. Is it possible to know that `func1` is used by this script without modifying code under `mypackage`, and maybe even copy these functions to a standalone file?

Comment: Without looking at the source code?  No.

Comment: By _used_, do you mean _called directly_?  i.e. what if your script calls `func1`, and then `func1` calls `func2`?

Comment: @JohnGordon I should say "without modifying the code in mypackage, but can do anything in the script as long as the results are not affected"

Comment: @JohnGordon not just directly, also those called indirectly, as long as under `mypackage`. Basically I'm trying to extract the code in `mypackage` that is just enough to be used by my script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, this seems impossible. Consider a conditional branch:

```
# myscript.py
import random

if random.random() < 0.5:
    func1()
else:
    func2()
```

We can't know until you actually run the script which function(s) it calls.

You could, however, see what functions it *did* call by defining your own trace function (see [`sys.settrace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.settrace)). Inside your tracer you'd check for function calls, inspect their module/package, and accumulate any of them which are owned by `mypackage` into a list.

Comment: Presumably the question was really asking for all the functions that the script _can possibly_ call, so in this case that would be both `func1()` and `func2()`.

Comment: @JohnGordon That's no easier. Can it _possibly_ call `if False: func1()`? What about `eval(input())()`? Sounds equivalent to the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

Comment: Strictly speaking you're right.  But I doubt OP intended to be that rigorous.  I imagine their question boils down to simply "what functions from mypackage are _mentioned textually_ in the script?"

Comment: @JohnGordon Maybe, maybe not. It could be a task of trying to identify unreachable code, for example, in which case just collecting the functions with textual analysis is not particularly useful. These details would have to be edited into the question.

Comment: @wim thanks for the feedback, I just added more context to the question

Comment: running the script is fine. In fact this is kind of like running the pdb debugger that tracks all the functions executed while running the script, except that I want it to be automated.

Comment: @DiveIntoML Then you can use the `'call'` event of the system trace, it should work well for this use-case (debuggers actually use this same feature!)